# How to display HTML page using BrightScript

Tags: html, gecko, roku, brightscript

I would like to display a single HTML web page on a Roku channel. I have no need to follow hyperlinks, but the page does have periodic updates.

Is it possible to write a BrightScript application that uses Gecko to render the page, or would I have to draw the page myself?

I see plenty of information as well as examples in the Roku SDK that describe how to provide user navigation and play video on a Roku box using BrightScript, but I can't find any information about displaying a single HTML page on a Roku channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use html code in roku app.

If you want to create something like web page in Roku app then use the roScreen in brightscript code and to show data you can use API.

Comment: Would that roscreen work as a full web page?? can we get it to work as  a web page with  navigation??

Comment: With roScreen you can draw images and text anywhere on the screen. So in this way you can get the GUI similar to your web page. But for navigation you have to use user inputs from Roku Remote. http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roUniversalControlEvent

Comment: @ abhishek:I keep getting error: Install Failure: No manifest. Invalid package.Install Failure: No manifest. Invalid package.Install Failure: No manifest. Invalid package.Install Success.Uninstall Success.Install Failure: No manifes when i try to upload a hello world sample from my browser..How can i fix it??

Comment: Just extract your zip file and check your folder structure. e.g. if your extracted package.zip then it should have package/source folder and package/manifest file . Make sure you have one .brs file in your source folder with main() function

Comment: I checked that and it was exactly what you said( i have a source folder with .brs file under tge package and the package itself contains a manifest file and just the source folder), moreover I have tried editing the one of the example's project changed the code of the main's fiunction to above specified code but still getting same error and not able to upload ...

Comment: @ abhishek This is how my manifest looks like:    title=Simple Info over Poster Screen Example
subtitle=Example of bringing up an InfoOverlay (MessageDialog in overlay mode)
major_version=1

Comment: sub Main()
 
  screen = CreateObject("roPosterScreen") 

  ' setup a message port so we can receive event information
  port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
  screen.SetMessagePort(port)


  screen.ShowMessage("Hello World!")
  screen.Show()

 
  while true
    msg = Wait(0, port) ' wait for an event

    if type(msg) = "roPosterScreenEvent"
      ' we got a poster screen event
      if msg.isScreenClosed()
        ' the user closed the screen
        exit while
      end if
    end if
  end while

  screen.Close()
 
end sub

Comment: any suggestion you can make here?

Comment: If your bright script code has any error you will never get this error  No manifest. Invalid package.Install Failure:                                                           This error comes only when you try to upload invalid zip file.

Comment: Thanks a ton I got it working...you are right I was zipping it wrong  way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use regex to convert html to simple text. This solution worked for our project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).