# Is there any way to display HTML content with its style in Roku SG?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I want to display HTML content like web in Roku SG.

I saw the solution for this problem, I used this solution that tells remove tags and then display only content but I want to display HTML content with its HTML style.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML page using BrightScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090024/how-to-display-html-page-using-brightscript)

Answer (score 4):

No.  There is no way to display HTML content using brightscript.