# Displaying HTML5 or HTML contents on Roku

Tags: html, roku, brightscript

Is there any possible way to display HTML OR HTML5 contents on ROKU OR Brightscript

Comment: which purpose you use in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any possible way to display HTML OR HTML5 contents on ROKU OR Brightscript

You can write roku code that fetches a web page from a URL but you cannot (at least not easily) write roku code that handles CSS or javascript.  You could obtain "contents" from an HTML web page, but you cannot display HTML on Roku.

Same question: [Is there any way to display HTML content with its style in Roku SG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608601/is-there-any-way-to-display-html-content-with-its-style-in-roku-sg)